# Test group existence in hdf5/c++

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am opening an existing HDF5 file for appending data; I want to assure that group called `/A` exists for subsequent access. I am looking for an easy way to either create `/A` conditionally (create and return new group if not existing, or return the existing group). One way is to test for `/A` existence. How can I do it efficiently?

According to the API docs, I can do something like this:

```
H5::H5File h5file(filename,H5F_ACC_RDWR);
H5::H5Group grp;
try{
   grp=h5file.openGroup("A");
} catch(H5::Exception& e){
   /* group does not exists, create it */
   grp=h5file.createGroup("A");
}
```

but the obvious ugliness comes from the fact that exception is used to communicate information which is not exceptional at all.

There is [H5::CommonFG::getObjinfo](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_common_f_g.html#a9832f8d8c05590650b1e8d48992622c1), which seems to wrap [H5Gget_objinfo](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5G.html#Group-GetObjinfo) in such way that false (nonexistent) return value of the C routine throws an exception; so again the same problem.

Is it clean to recourse to the C API in this case, or is there some function directly designed to test existence in the C++ API which I am overlooking?

Comment: It looks like the C++ equivalent of [`H5Lexists`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5L.html#Link-Exists) doesn't exist at all. The `try ... catch ...` seems much more pythonic than C++ to me, but I think that or using the C API are your two options.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Yossarian in his comment and [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468735/2838364) you can use HDF5 1.8.0+ C-API

```
bool pathExists(hid_t id, const std::string& path)
{
  return H5Lexists( id, path.c_str(), H5P_DEFAULT ) > 0;
}

H5::H5File h5file(filename,H5F_ACC_RDWR);
H5::H5Group grp;
if (pathExists(h5file.getId(), "A")) 
   grp=h5file.openGroup("A");
else
   grp=h5file.createGroup("A");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the solutions worked for me, here what I did.

```
H5:H5File file(filename, H5F_ACC_RWWR);
...
if(file.nameExists(groupname))
   return file.openGroup(groupname);
else
   return file.createGroup(groupname);
```

Comment: The `nameExists` method doesn't exist in 1.8.13 HDF5Cpp unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing the existence of a group with:

```
bool H5Location::attrExists(const char* name) const;
```

That way you can test the existence of group/dataset/… at the specified location.

```
// Test if empty (= new) H5 file
auto isNewFile = this->attrExists(VariablesH5GroupName);
```

Comment: Not 100% what I needed (I still have to check if it is a group and not some other attribute) but seems as good as it can get. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this only works if the group has a named attribute and that's not always the case… So it's not a correct answer, sorry :/

Comment: Just tried; with plain dataset, it will return false even if the dataset exists. Perhaps mark it more visible in the answer itself that it is not a correct one.